# Adding a custom JLabel to a JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jscrollpane

I'm creating an application that will allow the user to create a custom type of attack tree. When nodes are added to the tree, they are painted on a label. As soon as a certain amount of nodes is present on the same level of the tree, they no longer fit on the label. I added the label to a scrollpane and assumed the scrollbar would appear as soon as I try to paint something outside of the edges of the label, alas no. How can I achieve this?

Here is how I instantiate my frame:

```
    public ApplicationFrame() {
    super("Attack Tree GUI");

    tree = new AttackTree();
    rootNode = tree.getRoot();

    PageView label1 = new PageView(rootNode, tree);
    this.view = label1;

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(label1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    scrollPane.setViewportView(label1);

    contentPane.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, getToolBar());
    contentPane.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollPane);
    contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 900));

    setContentPane(contentPane);

    pack();
}
```

And here is the code for the PageView class:

```
public class PageView extends JLabel implements AttackTreeListener{

protected AttackTreeNode rootNode;
protected AttackTree tree;

public PageView(AttackTreeNode rootNode, AttackTree tree){
    this.rootNode = rootNode;
    this.tree = tree;
    rootNode.addListener(this);
    tree.addListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 

    // paints the page background
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    // paints the page frame
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    // Paint Nodes
    for(AttackTreeNode atn : tree.getNodes()) {
        paintTreeNode(atn, g2d);
    }

    // Paint Connections
    for(AttackTreeNode atn : tree.getNodes()) {
        if (!(atn.getChildren().isEmpty())){
            paintConnection(atn, g2d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to define the method `getPreferredSize()`, so the scroller can understand, that your component needs extra size. Implementing of interface `Scrollable` by your label would also be helpful.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy thank you, adding "this.setPreferredSize(...)" to the PageView constructor worked.

Comment: @LaurensL You should override `getPreferredSize` and calculate the amount of space you need based on the information you need to display. Not sure why you're using a `JLabel` as the base component,  a `JPanel` would be more suited